# lxml parse XML in python between 2 database using xpath function how to ?

Tags: python, xml, database, parsing

So, here's my game plan    .....

xpath in python[image]

Here's my xml

So this xml is stored in a database ( ca ) , I need to extract this "data" to get all these value layer out and store them to another database ( a )  :

Here's what's I came up so far..

```
import pyodbc
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO


con_ca = pyodbc.connect(..)
con_a  = pyodbc.connect(..)

cur_ca = con_ca.cursor()
cur_c = con_c.cursor() 

cur_ca.execute("""
select id_original,data
from table
""")

rows_ca = cur_ca.fetchall()
for row in rows_ca:

     id_original = id_original

     x = str(row.data)
     root = etree.fromstring(x)  

     BValid   = etree.XPath('/Data/Response/Detail/B/Valid')  
     BPass    = etree.XPath('/Data/Response/Detail/B/Pass')  
     BDetails = etree.XPath('/Data/Response/Detail/B/Details')  
     BCode    = etree.XPath('/Data/Response/Detail/B/Code')  
     BDecisionS = etree.XPath('/Data/Response/Detail/B/Decision/Result') 
     BDecisionB = etree.XPath('/Data/Response/Detail/B/Decision/Bucket') 



con_a.execute("""
INSERT INTO table2 (id_original,BValid,BPass,BDetails,BCode,BDecisionS BDecisionB) 
VALUES(?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?)
""")
```

.. everything work out , except after fetchall() 
I was able to get ('//text') : but how can I use Xpath to go into specific node to get value or text from this example ?

Comment: do you want to get a text element from the tree? like:

(b_valid_text,) = root.xpath('/Data/Response/Detail/B/Valid/text()')

Comment: Yes , I do but I couldn't figured it out what should I put to make this work.

Comment: well try the sample line I wrote here, that will get you the text element from '/Data/Response/Detail/B/Valid/', the same way you can get any of them, with the paths you already wrote.

Comment: Would it make more sense to store the information in the database instead of storing the xml in the database and then parsing the xml?

Comment: @Daenyth it would certainly , but it's not my choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
(b_valid_text,) = root.xpath('/Data/Response/Detail/B/Valid/text()')
```

Thanks Andrean! Just in case someone need that answer. This works!!